# How can I check if worksheet is empty?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have a `PhpSpreadsheetFileMerger` service in my application which simply merges multiple spreadsheet files (.xlsx) into one .xlsx. The issue is that some worksheets in the merged documents are empty. How can I check if a worksheet is empty? I recently upgraded from PhpExcel to PhpSpreadsheet and `empty($sheet->getCellCollection())` used to work, but now it doesn't.

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 0):

`empty($sheet->getCoordinates())` does the job.